# iphone sdk: Local notifications limitations

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone, uilocalnotification

[Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/WhatAreRemoteNotif/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW1) states:

> Each application on a device is limited to the soonest-firing 64
>   scheduled local notifications. The operating system discards
>   notifications that exceed this limit. It considers a recurring
>   notification to be a single notification.

Is that means when I schedule 64 local notifications in different times today I will not be able to schedule any local notification tomorrow or next week?

Answer (score 7):

**Maximum number of scheduled notification is 64**. If you are reached the maximum you can't add more local notifications without removing the old ones or after firing the scheduled notifications.

Comment: Correct ! just want to add one thing that the Recurring notifications will be considered as one.